# asp.net sitemap class to use another provider rather than default in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, sitemap, provider

I have this configuration in my web.config.

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="Provider1" enabled="true">
  <providers>
     <add name="Provider1" siteMapFile="Web.sitemap" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" />
     <add name="Provider2" siteMapFile="Web2.sitemap" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" />
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

In my C# code I use

```
SiteMap.RootNode.Url
```

which brings the Provider1 data. But I want to load Provider2 data without changing the default provider property. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SiteMap.Providers["Provider2"].RootNode.Url
```